# Can you change the color of camera composition lines?

Tags: camera

Sometimes, its hard to see the composition lines with white objects in the background. I know it is probably in the themes in the settings I just can't find it.

Comment: you change the active object color

Comment: or can u plz provide screen shot what basically you need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option to change the composition lines in the camera is located in the User Preferences Themes tab under 3D View. Its called View Overlay.